# Is li tag in html a inline-level or block-level element?

Tags: html, tags

I really wonder is a `li` tag in HTML a inline-level or block-level element?

I find that a `li` tag in a `p` tag can break a new line, so it's kind of like a block, but it's embedded in a `ul` tag or a `ol` tag.

From this point of view, it's kind of like a inline-level element? Which is right?

Comment: Block vs. inline isn’t the distinction used anymore (as of HTML5); see the last part of “Block-level vs. inline” at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements. `<li>` is “flow content”, per https://www.w3.org/TR/html/grouping-content.html#the-li-element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### NOTE: This is *intentionally* invalid markup to prove a point about block context.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:20px;">
      <p>
        <ul>
          <li>Hello</li>World
        </ul>
        Sagar 
      </p>
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

The W3School Definition of Inline and Block Element Stands as follows:

1. An **inline element** does not start on a new line and only takes up as much width as necessary.
2. A **block-level element** always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can).

As you can see in the example above, even though I typed "Hello" inside of the `li` tag and immediately followed it with "World", the single `li` tag will not allow the "World" to be on the same line. This demonstrates that the `li` tag is taking 100% of the available width, proving that `li` is a block level element.

That is my point of view.

Comment: W3Sch**ls is not the source of any standard, and your HTML is invalid.

Comment: I knowingly wrote invalid html to show that li tag will not allow any element in the line taking full width of available space. And I am not saying it a source of any standard it just contains a basic general definition of everything most likely like wikipedia , it is not about being correct but proving something by example

Comment: Using invalid markup makes the demonstration meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

An `li` element has a default display value of:

```
display:list-item
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

If it is set to `display:block` the default bullets will be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

dd, dt and li are listing items in HTML so I think block level elemnt's rule will work same for all dd, dt and li. For more solid proof visit this link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

here you will find all block level element listed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is really moot, since an `li` element must occur with a block-level `ul` or `ol`.

Answer (score -1):

Since it places theme selves one after one in a stacked manner, it is a block level element.

I am providing w3c documentation link where you can find more about this.
[visit this link](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html).

[image]

Comment: That section is about `<dd>`’s contents, not `<li>` itself.